# Python - evaluate shell command before executing it

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I have a Python function that I made with the subprocess package:

```
def run_sh(command):
    """Print output of bash command"""
    try:
        process = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=PIPE)
        for line in TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, newline=""):
            print(line)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(
                e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output
            )
        )
```

Let's say I want to run the following from within my Python script:

```
run_sh(newman run MY_COLLECTION.json "--env-var 'current_branch'=`git branch --show-current`")
```

Currently, it does not evaluate it as `git branch --show-current` but just treats it like test - how do I get it to evaluate it from my shell, and then run it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering.... ahouldn't the argument passed down to `run_sh` be a string? What does the interpreter show you as the output when you run this? Can you add it to the question? That would be great help.

Comment: If you want the *exact same effect* as using a shell, *use that shell*. If you want a much more limited effect—which is often the case, since passing un-sanitized user input *to* a shell is just begging for [this](https://xkcd.com/327/)—you'll have to work a lot harder.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code snippet that might help

```py
import subprocess

def run_command(cmd):
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
        if out:
            print(out.decode())
        if err:
            print(err.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_command('ls -l')
    run_command('ls -l /tmp')
    run_command('ls -l /tmp1')
```